# DIV contains varying number of divs, fill and cover remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is a container. I need to fill this container with other divs but the number of the items is changing. It could be 3 or 4 or even something else.

The height does not matter and the width is same for all.

I used `display: block` and `float: left` - it works, but there is empty space remaining. I want to force those item to cover the remaining space.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: how about `display: flex` for the parent and `flex-grow: 1` for the children? Or do you want to fill the remaining height too?

Comment: thank you so much. wonderful, this is exactly what i want, does it same for height?

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question.

Comment: Hi Ehsan - could we trouble you to choose a best answer -- or provide your own answer and select that -- to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will let you auto-resize elements the way you require.

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

#### DEMO:

```js
$('#adddiv').click(function(){
  $('#container').append('<div />');
});

$('#remdiv').click(function(){
  $('#container>div:last').remove();
});
```

```css
#container{display:flex;}
#container>div{flex:1;width:50px;height:50px;}

#container div:nth-child(1){background:green;}
#container div:nth-child(2){background:pink;}
#container div:nth-child(3){background:lightblue;}
#container div:nth-child(4){background:red;}
#container div:nth-child(5){background:palegreen;}
#container div:nth-child(6){background:yellow;}
#container div:nth-child(7){background:orange;}
#container div:nth-child(8){background:purple;}
#container div:nth-child(9){background:beige;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"><div></div></div>
<button id="adddiv">Add a Div</button>
<button id="remdiv">Remove a Div</button>
```

---

[Here is a very, very good (5min) video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)